# Unable to download CoraGraphDataset

Tags: python, graph, neural-network, dgl

```
import dgl.data 

dataset = dgl.data.CoraGraphDataset()
```

Error:

```
Downloading /Users/vinayakbali/.dgl/cora_v2.zip from https://data.dgl.ai/dataset/cora_v2.zip...
download failed, retrying, 2 attempts left
Downloading /Users/vinayakbali/.dgl/cora_v2.zip from https://data.dgl.ai/dataset/cora_v2.zip...
download failed, retrying, 1 attempt left
Downloading /Users/vinayakbali/.dgl/cora_v2.zip from https://data.dgl.ai/dataset/cora_v2.zip...

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='data.dgl.ai', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dataset/cora_v2.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

Manually downloaded the file and placed it under the .dgl directory. An alternative option would be to read the manually downloaded file. How that can be done at least ??

Answer (score 0):

Windows you can solve it as follow, I have already solved this problem
Go to --> setting --> Network& Internet --> Proxy --> Turn off Proxy